# changing URl parameter values

Tags: security, url

What is the best practise to do when user change the values of URL parameter?

- Redirect to login page.
- show error page with page is no exist message.
- still in the same page.

Comment: What I mean is, if user is not logged in and types protected page obviously login page. Otherwise, if he's allowed, go to page. If wrong url 404. Doesn't seem more to it then that. You could always have a 3rd case : redirect to closest match `/hom -> /home`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your URL should be defined that way that it always points to a resource.
2. There might be additional parts of the URL that are used to refine the resource (such as paging index or something else necessary only for that resource).
3. If a resource can be found - let the resource handle the wrong URL.
4. If the resource is not allowed to be accessed by the user -> login screen.
5. If no resource -> error.
6. no further case specified.

Comment: Do u know how much time u need to check the tree cases for each request?! It's too overload on the server !

Comment: You did ask for best practice, and this includes how do you structure your code. Ususally webframeworks let you define such URLs and link them to existing resources.